# Streaming websites do not give me the same image quality on Ubuntu as on Windows, how can I fix this?

Tags: drivers, graphics, video

I am trying to play movies and series on Amazon Prime videos and Netflix, but the quality is low compared to Windows. My laptop is the Asus Vivobook s15 OLED bape Edition model.

Graphics card: Intel Iris Xe Graphics
Processor: Intel Core i9-13900H

In Windows it gives me an excellent reproduction but, in Ubuntu it does not have the same performance. How can I improve this?

Video quality in Windows:

[image: quality in Windows]

Video quality in Ubuntu:

[image: quality in Ubuntu]

Comment: What is "I feel that the quality is low"? Do you actually know? Can you tell us?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? How it looks on windows and then another one of how to looks on Ubuntu?

Comment: add the images for reference

Comment: Netflix, at least, doesn't support the highest quality levels on Linux. https://help.netflix.com/en/node/30081 => max is 720p for any browser. For Prime Video, maybe try Chrome.